# Why P4python describe command doesn't return diff contents

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

If I send p4 describe command like below
"p4 describe CL_num"
I can get description and diff codes properly.

However when I use p4python code below
res_code = p4.run("describe", "CL Number")

This one only returns description without diff codes.
Same sitaution happens when I add -S option too.

How can I handle this problem?

Please let me know why there is difference between those two way of command.

and how can I get diff codes thorugh p4python?

Comment: You should consider rephrasing your question from "Why ... doesn't ...?" to something like "How to get the diff from ...?".

Comment: See linked duplicate -- the difference is that P4Python defaults to tagged mode (same as `p4 -Ztag describe CL_num`).